# I have design Tab in a Bootstrap 5 in row. And repeat row in ACF. only 1st row tab data is show. other row data off tabcontent appearing display:none

Tags: custom-field

" alt="Therapists Image" class="img-fluid" width="450" height="675" loading="lazy">

```
        <div class="skill-box"> 
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab-<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <button class="nav-link active" id="skills-tab-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#skills-<?php echo $i; ?>" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="skills-<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-selected="true">Skills</button>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
              <button class="nav-link" id="message-tab-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#message-<?php echo $i; ?>" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="message-<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-selected="false">Message</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent-<?php echo $i; ?>">
            
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="skills-<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="skills-tab-<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="0">
              <?php if(have_rows('skill_list')): ?>
              <ul>
                <?php while(have_rows('skill_list')): the_row(); ?> 
                <li><?php echo get_sub_field('skill_list_items'); ?></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
              </ul>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="message-<?php echo $i; ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="message-tab-<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="0">
              <div class="contact-box message-box">
                <?php 
                  echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="791e3d0" title="Send Message"]'); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
  $i++;
  endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.